# className is not a function

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code:

```
theAlert = document.createElement("div");
theAlert.className('alert alert-danger');
```

I get this error:

```
theAlert.className is not a function
```

What is wrong how come this doesn't work?

Comment: Yes ... ClassName is not a function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) is a getter/setter. It should be used like this:

```
theAlert.className = 'alert alert-danger';
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternate to @[KevBot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056157/kevbot)'s answer, you can also use [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Element.classList also provide APIs that comes handy and are declarative:

- Add
- Remove
- Toggle

**Sample:**

```js
document.getElementById('btnAdd').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.content').classList.add('color')
})

document.getElementById('btnRemove').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.content').classList.remove('color')
})

document.getElementById('btnToggle').addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.content').classList.toggle('color')
})
```

```css
.color{
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>Test</div>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
<button id="btnRemove">Remomve</button>
<button id="btnToggle">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: **Note:** This answer is an extension to KevBot's answer. Since he has already explained about `element.className`, explaining again would be duplication of content. So if there is anything apart from this, that is missing, please feel free to highlight along with your vote.